# Issues trying to copy file to dest folder with FileUtils.cp

Tags: ruby, fileutils

I have tried so many variations to the following line to try and get the file located at file_path to copy to the dest `"#{location}/#{customer}/#{version}/"` but I continually get the error that `"#{location}/#{customer}/#{version}/"` is a folder.

The Ruby 1.9.3 docs it says that if `dest` is a folder it will copy to `dest/src`... so I'm at a loss here.

```
FileUtils.cp("#{file_path}", "#{location}/#{customer}/#{version}/")
```

Where file_path is

```
/home/testing/files/blah.txt
```

and `"#{location}/#{customer}/#{version}/"` resolves to:

```
/home/testing/backup/customername/versionnumber/
```

I know I'm probably doing something really easily fixable but I have tried many things including:

```
FileUtils.cp(file_path, "#{location}/#{customer}/#{version}/")
FileUtils.cp("#{file_path}", '#{location}/#{customer}/#{version}/')
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I have also tried setting dest to the location first:
    dest = "#{location}/#{customer}/#{version}/"

Comment: Is your src a file or a directory? Above, you've implied `/home/testing/files/blah.txt` is a file. Is it possible you are trying to copy a directory?

Comment: Yes src is a file and dest is a dir. But in the documentation it says that IF dest is a dir it will copy to dest/src.

Comment: Yeah, thats what it did when I tried it.

Comment: This is messed up. Is your src just a file or is it /folder/file? Maybe it has something to do with that my src is actually a location to a file and just explicitly just a file? No idea now.

Comment: `FileUtils.cp("/hme/testing/files/blah.txt", "/hme/testing/backup/customername/versionnumber")` works for me after creating all those directories.

Comment: Hmm I think I have found the root problem possibly. FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname("#{location}/#{customer}/#{version}")) doesn't appear to be creating the dir. I'll look into that

Comment: Fixed the problem. SOrry guys, changed FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname("#{location}/#{customer}/#{version}")) to FileUtils.mkdir_p("#{location}/#{customer}/#{version}")

Answer (score 0):

If anything under `file_path` is a directory and not a file, FileUtils.cp will definitely throw `Errno::EISDIR: Is a directory`.

If that's your situation, you would need to use FileUtils.cp_r instead.